# Is there a way to schedule kv file load using clock or something else in kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am new to kivy/python and trying to develop an Kivy app with multiple kv files.
Is there any way to schedule few kv files to run in the future/to run in the background. I mean after the application starts?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine why you would want to do this. Typically,  a `kv` file contains rules for building `Widgets` (indicated by `<>`) and, at most, one `root` `Widget` (indicated by the lack of `<>`). The `root` `Widget` must be loaded before the `App` runs, and the `<>` rules have no effect until an instance of that `Widget` is created. What are you trying to accomplish by scheduling the loading of a `kv` file?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have lots of images(JPG/PNG) in my kivy app.I think processing takes time because of this.I am getting blank screen for 30 seconds after app loaded on android.. I am using ScreenManager as rootwidget to manage screens and each screen has mostly Image/Imagebutton/Label widgets.So I thought i will split the kv file and load few files later. But from your response i understood kv files should be loaded before app runs.  Is there any other way i can load some of my image widgets in the background so that app opens quick ?Else how we can avoid this 30 seconds wait time.

Comment: You could create the `ScreenManager` and the first `Screen` on the main thread, then create the other `Screens` in a separate thread. So the second thread would do things like `scr2 = Screen2()` and `screenManager.add_widget(scr2)`. But, before doing anything like that, I would suggest adding some code to your App to measure how long  building the screens actually takes.

Comment: Sorry i could not catch you. Separate thread means, Is it a new kv file ? Currently i have declared all the screens in main.kv file and it has only widgets for the main window screen. In another kv file i have added widgets to the remaining screens. So scr2 = Screen2() and screenManager.add_widget(scr2) where you want me to add and try? And this screen load happens after app starts or before?

Comment: You could start another thread that loads, for example, the `kv` file that defines `Screen2`, and then creates a `Screen2` instance and adds it to the `ScreenManager`. Such a thread could be started in the `build()` method of your `App`. But again, I would urge you to do some simple time measurements before going down this road. Just comment out lines that load the second `kv` file and lines that build the remaining `Screens`. Try running that modified code and compare how long it takes to start the `App`. That will give you an idea of the best improvement you can achieve with this approach.